# Copying issue with home directory

Tags: home-directory, lamp

I am new to Ubuntu and i was wondering why i am unable to copy Codeigniter folder in downloads to another folder in the home directory? I just installed lamp and setup a another folder by following this [guide](http://1024bitez.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/change-documentroot-of-apache-webserver.html) and fear i may have messed something up.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  Could you provide more information?

Comment: I am not getting any errors just paste doesn't work. sorry i can't give more details as i very new to this and the command line is a bit daunting at the moment.

Comment: @Snotbox Are you unable copy text from the command-line and paste it into your question? If so, is this because you have a command-line only system with no GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you used sudo to unpack a tarball, or something to that effect, which made the  created directory be owned by root. Fire up a terminal and try this:

```
sudo chown -R snotbox:snotbox ~/Downloads/Codeigniter
```

Replace snotbox with your username, and remember that the file path is case sensitive. i.e. ~/Downloads/Codeigniter is not the same as ~/Downloads/codeigniter.